# Creating a summary table on BigQuery aggregating multiple values in a row

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to create a table like below, aggregating by payment method, where I can see a summary of the combinations of services used in one day. In this case, combinations (A, B) in `service_type` would be the same as (B, A), and (A, A, C) would be the same as (A, C). I need to use BigQuery, and I don't know how to generate all the combinations for `service_type` without manually printing them out. `no_of_service` is the number of services grouped in `service_type`, and `total_orders` is the number of unique `customer_id`s which purchased that specific combination of orders in that date.

```
order_date  no_of_service  service_type  total_orders  order_payment
2018-04-03      1               A              5            CASH
2018-04-03      1               B              4            CASH
2018-04-03      1               C              1            CASH
2018-04-03      1               D              10           CASH
2018-04-03      1               E              5            CASH
2018-04-03      3               A,C,D          10           CREDIT
2018-04-03      3               B,D,E          5            CREDIT
2018-04-02      1               A              8            CREDIT
2018-04-02      1               C              7            CREDIT
```

The `daily_order` table which I'm querying from has the columns `order_payment` (CASH, CREDIT, etc), `service_type` (A, B, C, etc), `customer_id` (unique value for each customer), and `order_time` (e.g. 2018-04-06 15:06:26 UTC). It looks like this:

```
order payment  service_type  customer_id  order_time
CASH           A             58128        2018-04-06 15:06:26 UTC
CREDIT         B             58256        2018-04-06 15:08:34 UTC
```

Comment: Please normalize your table and remove that CSV data.

Comment: Sorry, can you explain this a little bit? I need the values to be printed out that way, e.g. A,B,C

Comment: @nomorecookies . . . You need to show sample data that corresponds to the desired results.  Just one or two rows might be sufficient.