# How can I create a distribution table with SQL without manually listing out all the values in the query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to make a table like below, which gives me a distribution of the number of orders made by a single customer ID

```
no_of_orders  count_of_customer_id
1             537
2             845
3             193
4             80
...           ...
```

How do I do this without manually printing out the no_of_orders (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...) in the query, As I expect there will be outliers which make hundreds of orders a day. I will be using BigQuery for this.

The daily_order table which I'm querying from has the columns **order_payment** (CASH, CREDIT, etc), **service_type** (A, B, C, etc), **customer_id** (unique value for each customer), and **order_time** (e.g. 2018-04-06 15:06:26 UTC). It looks like this:

```
order payment  service_type  customer_id  order_time
CASH           A             58128        2018-04-06 15:06:26 UTC
CREDIT         B             58256        2018-04-06 15:08:34 UTC
```

Comment: Is this a homework question [like this other similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55234118/creating-a-summary-table-on-bigquery-aggregating-multiple-values-in-a-row)?  Or do you have two different SO accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, use a select query to retrieve no_of_order for each customer by grouping customer_id and then from this query use another query to group each count.

```
select no_of_orders, count(*) as count_of_customer_id 
  from(
    select count(*) as no_of_orders 
      from daily_order 
      group by customer_id
  ) 
  group by no_of_orders 
  order by no_of_orders;
```